# Cost Query with having and >

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping, sql-execution-plan, having-clause

I have the next query :

```
select code
  from user
  group by code
  having 
    sum(case when name= 'A' then 1 end) >
    sum(case when name= 'A' then 1 end)
```

If i check the cost of the query it says it's 180, but if I use '=' instead of >, the cost is 1 , so does anyone have any idea why this is happening? why it's only using the index with '=' and not with '<'

Comment: I am guessing that this is just a bug in the optimizer.  I would imagine that the two queries have the same execution plan.

Comment: Are you sure the costs are that way round? I could see it spotting that the `>` condition could never be true and knowing it had no work do really do, but then that would get the low cost. I wouldn't have thought it would use an index for either, unless you have one that covers both the name and code columns maybe.

Comment: Don't worry about what the optimizer says what the "cost" is. It's not the cost you're thinking of. You can't compare costs between queries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a real query? I'm asking because the query is invalid - having clause is equal to writing `1 > 1`, so always False... And if you replace '>' with '=' the query is always true unless the result from sum() is NULL...